# Node.js - Install webpack with npm - npm ERR! 400 Bad Request - GET http://registry.npmjs.org/webpack

Tags: command-line, installation, npm

I have an issue with installing webpack using npm for Node.js;

- Version of node: 12.16.0
- Version of npm: 6.13.4

Error received is:

```
npm ERR! code E400
npm ERR! 400 Bad Request - GET http://registry.npmjs.org/webpack
```

The log below:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   'webpack',
1 verbose cli   '--save-dev'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.13.4
3 info using node@v12.16.0
4 verbose npm-session f29f76802f82d299
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readLocalPackageData
7 http fetch GET 400 http://registry.npmjs.org/webpack 173ms
8 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for webpack@latest 400 Bad Request - GET http://registry.npmjs.org/webpack
9 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 1ms
10 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 234ms
11 verbose stack Error: 400 Bad Request - GET http://registry.npmjs.org/webpack
11 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-fetch\check-response.js:104:15
11 verbose stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
12 verbose statusCode 400
13 verbose pkgid webpack@latest
14 verbose cwd C:\Users\amonea\Desktop\Personal\Programs\complete-javascript-course-master\9-forkify
15 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18363
16 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "webpack" "--save-dev"
17 verbose node v12.16.0
18 verbose npm  v6.13.4
19 error code E400
20 error 400 Bad Request - GET http://registry.npmjs.org/webpack
21 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: 400 Bad Request

The server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing).

Comment: Does it only do that when you try to install `webpack` or does it do it for other npm packages as well?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by manually removing npm from my computer, deleted npm folder in the path C:\Users<USER>\AppData\Roaming and reinstalled npm with the node installer